# How to check if all tuples have a specific value in a python list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I am a newbie to python and I am struggling to find a better way for a problem.

I have a list like below:

```
 [(1048, u'3', u'1', ), (1048, u'03', u'00','Deleted' ), (1048, u'4', u'0', 'Deleted')]
```

In each tuple, the last attributed could be 'deleted' or 'None'. I need to check if all tuples have 'deleted' at last place.

How to do that.

I tried to do list comprehension (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
object_with_specific_attribute = [dataObj for dataObj in data if "Deleted" in dataObj[3]]
```

but it does not seem to be working in case of null data.

Can anybody please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about checking every tuple -1 position and check if that is Deleted or not

Comment: Shashank, instead of suggesting a partial solution in a comment, please suggest a full answer as answer instead.

Comment: It is unclear whether last item could be None (as None value) or missing from the tuple (no value at all).

Comment: @Jérôme based on the example provided above it appears that it would be entirely missing. I assume the process that writes those tuples out is not the best..

Comment: @Jerome: both cases are possible. ie: value also can be none or element itself cannot be present.

Comment: @Lovey Please edit your question with the info you just provided.

Comment: So you expect "Deleted", None or just no value. In this case, this means the nb of values is always 4, except when the last is missing, which means 3 items is equivalent to 3 items + None or 3 items + Deleted and is accepted, which means that checking item -1 is wrong, AFAIU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
all(item[-1] == "Deleted" for item in items)
```

This should return `True` if they all contain "Deleted"

Also all your tuples need to have at least 4 elements. If not, you will get an index error

EDIT: As it stands in the comments it is better to go with `item[-1]` as you stated: "last element"

Comment: OP says *last item* so it might be better to go with index `[-1]` in case some of the tuples for some reason have more or less elements.

Comment: I think by "None", the OP means the 4th element is absent. `(1048, u'3', u'1', )[-1]` is `1` so this solution does not handle this @Ev.Kounis

Comment: @Chris_Rands True but i still think it is better than `[3]`. A separate check has to be made for the absence or the 4th value. Some of the other solutions check the lenght too. OP has not been very clear as to what the tuples might or might not look like.

Answer (score 4):

```
all(len(tup) == 3 or tup[-1] in [None, "Deleted"] for tup in data)
```

From your example it is inferable some tuples have no 4th item, so I added the `len` check.

Answer (score 0):

Below line would work.

```
object_with_specific_attribute = [tup for tup in data if tup[-1] == 'Deleted']
```